# Enable encrypted communications in FIWARE between Orion - IoT-AgentJson?

Tags: security, fiware, fiware-orion

I want to enable TLS communications between:

- Orion ←→ IoTAgentJson

I have reviewed the documentation for Orion and IoTAgentJson, however, it is not entirely clear to me.

IotAgentJson includes some environmental variables `IOTA_HTTP_KEY` and `IOTA_HTTP_CERT`. However, the documentation indicates ["HTTP-related environment variables will be used in the upcoming HTTP binding"](https://fiware-iotagent-json.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installationguide.html#http-binding-configuration). I assume it relates to devices connecting via HTTP and not to communicate with Orion.

Any leads?

Answer (score 3):

There are specific configuration parameters to establish IotAgent->CB communication, but probably it's not documented in the best way

Try this at config.js file, supposed your CB is behind a proxy providing HTTPS protocol:

```
contextBroker: {url: 'https://xxxxxxx:xxx'}
```

If you use envvars to configure the iotAgent use this instead:

```
IOTA_CB_URL
```

If you need extra security and you have got a PEP proxy in between you may need to specify auth config:

```
 authentication: {
        enabled: true,
        type: 'keystone',
        header: 'X-Auth-Token',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '0000',
        user: 'xxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxx'
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I am using `fiware/iotagent-json:1.26.0`. Is there a way to interact with `contextBroker: {url: 'https://xxxxxxx:xxx'}` from environmental variables?

Comment: then you may use: IOTA_CB_URL (https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/f7badab7b137f31bdfd0eca1af820bfb2e1f5a66/lib/commonConfig.js#L110)